# How do I add a new device for provisioning on the Apple Developer site when the button is disabled?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-provisioning

My add device button in prov. portal is grayed out (disabled) like in the screenshot:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Err, do you need to reset your device list, like it says in a big yellow bar?

Comment: I know its a silly question, but are you an Admin or a simple member? because only the admin has the right to add devices.

Comment: The wording on this is message from Apple is TERRIBLE! It makes you think that you have to erase your list of devices.  Fortunately, that is not the case.  It should say "renew your device list".  Clicking this will NOT "reset" it, i.e. it will not erase it (thank god!).

Comment: What @BuvinJ said, this will not delete your devices from the list, only give you the option to deselect those you no longer use and make room for new ones

Comment: Thank you BuvinJ!  That's exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: @BuvinJ When this "Reset your device list before adding any new devices" appeared to you? On the day of your renewal? I have already renew my account (before the date due to) and this is still not appearing. It will appear only on the "Device Reset Date" specified on Apple Developer?

Comment: @MatiasJurfest I don't recall that detail with certainty.  But, I strongly suspect your guess is correct. I *think* they limit you to X number of devices, and keep you locked into the list until your anniversary date, so you can't swap devices in and out.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. Click on "Get Started Button"
2. Check / uncheck devices that you want
3. Check box that says you acknowledge terms and conditions
4. Hit Submit
5. Add button will be available again

I just did all those steps.

Comment: i have an question that. My membership year will expires on 31 march 2015 but i have renewed my membership on 1st Feb 2015. 
So the "Reset Device" popup or option will enable after 31st March 2015 or this will enable anytime. 
After renewed my membership i have not seen this option till today.

Comment: You should point out like @BuvinJ in the comments it will not erase nor reset your device list.

Comment: This solution working fine. Resetting in the sense, remove unwanted devices list and keep used devices in new membership year. I think this message is coming for newly renewed accounts.

Comment: @V.J. I have the same issue. How did you solve this? "Reset Device" popup appeared only on 31st March 2015?

Comment: @MatiasJurfest I have to wait until i receive Reset Device popup. There is no option other than this.

Answer (score 7):

Before doing something please note the following from Apple renewal policy:

**Important Note:** At the start of your membership year, make sure to remove all devices you no longer use for development prior to adding any new devices.

Refer to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html)

Please, DO NOT add any new devices until you have removed all of the ones that you want to remove. Once you add a device, all of the existing devices will be re-registered.

What you need to do is simple: Get started, follow Sam's steps above. And start adding your new devices once your existing device list is renewed.

Answer (score 4):

##### Updated answer for 2022

1. Go to [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list).
2. At the top you will see a banner saying *"Before adding new devices, make sure your device list is updated for the new membership year. You have the option to remove devices from your list."*. Press `Continue` in that banner.
3. You will see a list of your existing devices. If you want to keep all of them, just press `Continue`, otherwise deselect the ones you no longer want to use.
4. You will see a headline saying *"Confirm your devices and reset."*. At the bottom you need to check the checkbox saying *"
   I acknowledge that any devices I disable during this membership year will continue to count towards my total registered devices."*.
5. Now it get's Apple level counter-intuitive - you need to press the button called `Reset`. Yes, this is Apples way of saying `Confirm`, `Save` or `Submit`. To ordinary people however, it sounds like you're resetting the list, i.e. clearing it.

If you're new to App Store Connect, you'd better get used to counter-intuitive, vague and downright misleading wordings like these.

Answer (score 2):

Reset your devices, you will get the option to transfert previous devices. Press "get started"

Answer (score 1):

no worries go ahead with with reset as you've started a new membership year, you can remove unwanted devices from your account and reset your registered device list. By default, your enabled devices are pre-selected and disabled devices are not selected.
Select the devices you wish to carry over to this membership year or deselect the devices you want to remove.
you will get the following message.
*"I acknowledge that any devices I disable during this membership year will continue to count towards my total registered devices"*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to reset your devices list with help of Get Started button then one popup will appear and follow the steps and once done create provisioning profile button will enable and you can create profile then.